# How to shift Vuetify component ```VDatePicker``` according to the position of its parent component on the screen

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using `VMenu` component from vuetify and inside it is another vuetify component `VDatePicker`. The functionality is such that when I click a text field, the calender(VDatePicker) is seen. The `VDatePicker` component appears normally always under the text field, provided there is enough space under the field until the end of the screen.

But now the problem is that the text field is positioned such that there is little space between it and the end of the screen, so the DatePicker tries to adjest itself and pushes itself a little above and hence it hides the field underneath (snap shot attached).

The question is that How can I shift it such that when such a case occurs where there is little space between field and end of screen then it should position itself at the top of the filed and not on it.[image]

Comment: This is a suggestion: https://codepen.io/Jubels/pen/ydjPPq. If don't have it as a `vMenu` then you can apply any styling you want much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to shift it to the side?
You can use `nude-right="300px"` in the `v-menu`to nudge the Datepicker 300px to the right

Sample:
https://codepen.io/j3n50m4t/pen/xxZzVLG